# What does "Merging down" and "Copying up" mean in perforce streams?

Tags: perforce, perforce-stream

I'm currently working with the perforce API for .net. I'm trying to understand the concept of streams and graphical view of the streams.

"Merging down" changes from a source stream and "Copying up" changes to a stream are the two terms I came across. I'm not really clear about the difference, because based on this only, the stream graph is getting generated.

This is the URL, which I'm looking into now. [P4V streams](https://www.perforce.com/perforce/r12.3/manuals/p4sandbox/04_usegui.html).

Can someone please tell me what it means?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Merging involves blending files together.
Changes that conflict will need to be resolved.

Copying involves copying/replacing a file in one location with another.

Perforce Helix uses the 'mainline' model with Streams.
This involves merging down in to less stable streams (via the mainline) and copying up in to the more stable streams (again via the mainline).

You can find more information about this here:
  https://www.perforce.com/video-tutorials/mainline-model

Hope this helps,
Jen.